# Search Multiple sites with one input field

Tags: html, forms, search, input

**how about when you down vote something you leave a comment on why you down voted so the poster has an idea how they can improve on the way they asked something**

So I have an input field like so:

```
<form action="search.php?do=process" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="do" value="process" />
 <input type="hidden" name="quicksearch" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="childforums" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="exactname" value="1" />
 <input type="hidden" name="s" value="$session[sessionhash]" />
 <input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="$bbuserinfo[securitytoken]" />
 <input type="text" name="query" tabindex="1001" id="overlay-search" class="no-border overlay-search bg-transparent" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" />
</form>
```

what I'm trying to accomplish is alternative buttons that will search the text in the input on say google.com but I have had no success in finding a solution to this =/

the way I'm trying to get it to work is like:

```
Not happy with your results? <a href="http://google.com/WHAT EVER THERE SEARCH STRING IS/TEXT IN INPUT">Try searching on google.</a>
```

I have searched and searched and have found nothing related to this, although I doubt I'm searching the right thing.  Any help in achieving this would be greatly appreciated =)

### searches I'm considering on including:

- Facebook
- Google
- Bing
- Yahoo
- and more

Comment: You do realize that `$session[sessionhash]` and `$bbuserinfo[securitytoken]` is just text, right? It will not be processed by PHP.

Comment: these are variables used in vBulletin templates =) they function just fine

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution will be getting the value of the posted input field and just echoing out .Before that you must add a submit button at the end of your form.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>
```

And then do something like below in your search.php file.

```
        <?php 
            // Check if the submit button is clicked
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
            // And then do something

                echo 'Not happy with your results?<a href="http://google.com'.$_POST['query'].'">Try searching on google.</a>";

            }
        ?>
```

Comment: I like this solution, although what if PHP wasn't an option? ...it is, but just a little harder to achieve.  I use vBulletin and this is for a template which doesn't allow PHP.

Comment: Sorry but i have never used vbulletin .. The basic rule is that you attach the query string in the url link like like above.If you cant run any server side script then you must do it in javascript