# Replace div with input field text jQuery

Tags: jquery, forms, text, input, replace

Ok Ive been trying to solve my own issue I posted here
[Search Multiple sites with one input field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28656122/search-multiple-sites-with-one-input-field)

One way I see of doing it is using jQuery to replace a div and show only the text then in the long run i can do something like

```
<input type="test.....

<a href="http://google.com/q=<div id="placeholder"></div>">Search on google</a>
```

and just have the Jq replace the div and it would be a functional link, or so that's the idea.

although I'm having issues with the jq, replaceWith doesn't want to seem to grab more than just the first letter typed.

I set up what I have so far here.

http://jsbin.com/xosafogaya/1/edit?html,js,output

will this even work for what I'm wanting in the long run?  If so how can I make it register more than just the first letter typed?

Comment: `replaceWith()` remove the element so it no more exists after first call. You should use `.text()` or `.html()` and `keyup()` event instead of keypress which is fired before value is set, e.g: `$('#myInputText').keyup(function(e) {
              $("#myDIVTag").text(this.value);
            });`

Comment: for the end result i need the div to be gone, cant have tags in a link.  If i kept the tags the end result would be like <a href="google.com/q=<div... and that just wont work =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/9r246chg/

Here is a working demo. and the code inside is as such

html

```
<input id="myInputText" type="text" name="inputBox" />
<a id="anchor" target="_blank" href="">Search on google</a>
```

javascript/jquery

```
$('#myInputText').on('input', function (e) {
$("#anchor").attr("href", "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl#q=" + $(this).val());
$("#anchor").html("Search " + $(this).val() + " on google");
});
```

notice all I'm doing is detecting a change on the input and then setting the attribute and inner html.